# How to spilt and format the contents of an array in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script which looks for non-standard user accounts in  the local admin group of my windows servers and it goes ahead and removes them. I then have the result to out to a HTML page. The thing is that I am saving the removed user names in an empty array using $adm+= $member, which gets populated as it finds users to be removed.
The thing is that when in the console I see the output of the newly populated array which at this point is $adm the result is displayed in a list format, but when outputted to a website its horizontal, for example on the webpage it shows up as "kab2386""kab6522""kab3422". With no spaces and in the same line. So my question is can we have this array to display output in a list fashion instead showing up in a single line?

Comment: maybe i can using a foreach loop and spilt the contents of this array? to display on a new line for each element?

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to diagnose the problem. Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially how to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will add the HTML line breaks:

```
$adm -join "<br>" | Out-File
```

So, join the array with the line break tags and export the String for your page.

Comment: Can I represent the array I have into a string and then export it to a csv? Coz right now if I export it, in the CSV file it gives me the length value